# Runnable class object

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I don't have much experience with threading in Java. How can I get the value of String ft all way from inside Runnable(){} to use it in main().

```
public class testInner {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Outer out =new Outer();
        out.makeinner();
        System.out.println("main :" + out.getft());
    }
}
public class Outer {
    private volatile String ft;
    public String getft(){
        return ft;
    }
    public void makeinner(){
        inner in = new inner();
        in.changeOuter();
    }
    public class inner{
        public void changeOuter(){
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    ft = "what?";
                    System.out.println("run :" + ft);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Result when compiled:

```
main :null
run :what?
```

Comment: sounds like you're looking for something akin to `CompletableFuture<String>` (something computes a string in a diff thread, which you retrieve on completion and print it out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads are executed in parallel, so you can't be sure the thread has been successfully executed when you do `System.out.println("main :" + out.getft());`. This is why you get `null`, the thread didn't edit that variable yet.

If you want to be sure the thread finishes the execution, use `join`:

```
public class inner{
    public void changeOuter(){
        Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                ft = "what?";
                System.out.println("run :" + ft);
            }
        });
        myThread.start();
        myThread.join(); // wait for the thread to finish before returning

    }
}
```

Comment: Though, it does seem very redundant to wait for a thread to finish to do anything in this case.